# MVC Controller to return valid XML sitemap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitemap

I have an ASP .NET MVC site that calls a Web API to get the sitemap xml. The MVC site then provides the public endpoint/address.

The API builds the correct XML string which looks something like this...

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www...</loc>
<lastmod>2017-09-03</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.../forbusiness</loc>
<lastmod>2017-09-03</lastmod>
</sitemap>...
```

The API controller looks like this...

```
[Route("api/sitemap")]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var siteMap = _siteMapService.GetSitemapXml();

    return new HttpResponseMessage() { Content = new StringContent(siteMap, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml") };
}
```

The end point in the MVC application looks like this...

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("sitemap.xml")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SitemapXml()
    {
      using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://...");
         var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/sitemap");
         var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         return Content(xml, "text/xml");
      }
    }
```

When this endpoint is hit the XML that is returned looks something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www...</loc>
<lastmod>2017-09-03</lastmod>
</sitemap>
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www....</loc>
<lastmod>2017-09-03</lastmod>
</sitemap>...
```

The problem I am having is that there is a double declaration on the top to the XML which makes the site map invalid...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

If I remove the content type from the MVC app the sitemap is still invalid as it is returned as HTML.

How should I return this sitemap as a valid XML sitemap?